# Is there a way to easily wrap or extend Angular-material directives in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-directive

I am using the angular-material library here and there in an angular5 application, but I don't want its directive/component/class names in my markup, which I prefer to keep agnostic with respect to external libraries.  However, I tried doing something like this:

```
import { Directive, 
         ElementRef, 
         Renderer, 
         Renderer2 }  from "@angular/core";

import { MatButton }  from "@angular/material";
import { OnInit }     from "@angular/core";
import { Platform}    from "@angular/cdk/platform";
import {FocusMonitor} from "@angular/cdk/a11y";

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-button]'
})
export class MyButtonDirective extends MatButton {

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  constructor(renderer: Renderer2, elementRef: ElementRef, _platform: Platform, _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor) {
    super(renderer, elementRef, _platform, _focusMonitor);

  }
}
```

But when I apply the `my-button` attribute, it seems to have no effect whatsoever.  Even `console.logs` from inside the directive constructor/onInit are not printed.  I'm not real sure what I'm doing wrong as I've never used directives before in Angular.

Comment: Why are you applying `ubi-button` attribute when your directive has `my-button` selector?

Comment: oh sorry, i meant to type my-button, i changed the prefix for this post but then typed the wrong one here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much further you'd get, but you said you are using an attribute, when maybe you want to use an element Test

Answer (score 0):

you are missing your template.
Extends only give access to your code but template is not automatically extended.

this is similar..when you create npm package for your component. You are required to export class and then template.